# latex beamer no shadow on title

Tags: beamer, shadows

I use beamer class with Warsow Style.

I use rounded with shadow box for the : alert, block and example.

However I also get a shadow rounded box on the first slide on my title.

My question is show to remove the shadow rounded box on my title on the first page ?

Thanks

Comment: A MWE here would really help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the `title page` template to suppress the shadow (this will leave the shadow for the blocks unaltered):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{exampleblock}{Example}
Test
\end{exampleblock}
\begin{alertblock}{Alert}
Test
\end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it is exactely what I wanted to do ;)

Comment: I found the above answer have a problem, that is, the title block is not in the center strictly. It just "removes" the shadow. Another question I would like to ask is that how to let the title block on a part page get rid of shandow as well, if a presentation is divided into some parts and the commanders \part and \partpage are used. Thanks.